# In which subversion of gcc 4.8 was the std::promise & std::future introduced

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

In which subversion of gcc 4.8 was the std::promise & std::future introduced? Had a look at the release info by gcc.gnu.org.

I guess these features fall under concurrency category as a sub-category of some other feature. But the column just mentions supported in 4.8

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Do you have this information?

Comment: The [changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) doesn't say :(

Comment: I can confirm that they're present in gcc version 4.8.2 20140120

Comment: From what I can see they were added before 4.8.  According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) experimental support was added in 4.5 and [the change log for 4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) has *Improved experimental support for the new ISO C++ standard, C++11, including: [...] enabling the thread support library on most POSIX targets;*

Comment: Gcc does not add features in patch-level versions, only fixes bugs. So if it is in 4.8.x, it will be there from 4.8.0. However, 4.8 only has partial support for futures.